# How to make client side user persist across page refreshes and navigations using Nest.js and JWT

Tags: reactjs, jwt, nestjs, tsx

I am currently working on a small piece of a larger project using Nest and React. The server-side auth has already been completed using JWT. We've already built out the login function. See below code snippet:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

import type { Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import EmailInput from './EmailInput';
import FacebookAuthBtn from './FacebookAuthBtn';
import GoogleAuthBtn from './GoogleAuthBtn';
import PasswordInput from './PasswordInput';
import StyledLink from './StyledLink';
import TextDivider from './TextDivider';
import { UserContext } from './providers';


...
interface UserLoginData {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

const initialFormData: UserLoginData = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
};
function Login() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [, setUser] = React.useContext(UserContext);

    const [ formData, setFormData ] = React.useState(initialFormData);

    const handleChange = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        const { name, value }: { name: string; value: string } = evt.target;
        setFormData((fData) => ({
            ...fData,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (evt: React.FormEvent) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/auth/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                // credentials: "include",
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            });
            const response = await res.json();
            // TODO replace placeholder with .env var
            const user = jwt.verify(response.access_token, 'placeholder');
            setUser(user);
            history.push('/');
        } catch (err) {
            // Handle error
        }
    };

    return (...)
```

So building off the handleSubmit function, after I have JSON my response, I need to, I guess, do some authentication? My goal is to write the code, on the client side, where the user persist across page refreshes and naviations.

Any tips or suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: To persist between page refreshes, you'll need to use localStorage, sessionStorage, or cookies to save the JWT.  Localstorage API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.  I'd suggest reading up on the vulnerabilities that exist with each of those as well.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention I want to use cookies.

Comment: In short, you can place your JWT token inside a cookie and send it to the user's browser upon logging in, in the response headers. Then simply upon any request to your server extract the JWT from the cookie and validate it. See ex. https://matthiasschild.medium.com/jwt-authentication-with-nestjs-and-http-only-cookies-a338f5baeff9